# Acqua fredda o ...?

Tags: adjectives, phrase-request, vocabulary

A volte succede che mi manca un adeguato vocabolario per esprimere i fatti della vita quotidiana. Quando si è in un bar, un ristorante, una trattoria o qualche altro locale di ristorazione e si vuol ordinare dell'acqua per bere, quale aggettivo o espressione si deve usare per indicare che si vorrebbe l'acqua a temperatura ambiente?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

“A temperatura ambiente”! Credo che sia il modo più diffuso; ho anche sentito, per sottolineare la richiesta, “non di frigo”.

Comment: Veramente curioso! Mi sembra un modo di esprimersi molto scientifico!

Comment: Per curiosità, come si dice in catalano?

Comment: `Fuori frigo` viene anche usato spesso dalle mie parti. Ma senza dubbio `(a) temperatura ambiente` (anche senza la "a": acqua temperatura ambiente) viene usato più spesso

Comment: @DaG: In catalano diciamo "aigua natural". So che in italiano "acqua naturale" significa "acqua senza gas".

Answer (score 3):

Propongo, come opzione alternativa, "acqua (naturale / frizzante) non fredda".