# Differenze di uso tra "ristoro" e "ristorazione"

Tags: word-usage, difference

Quando ho scritto [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5529/707) ho avuto il dubbio su quale parola usare, "ristoro" oppure "ristorazione". La frase è stata poi scritta così: "Quando si è in un bar, un ristorante, una trattoria o qualche altro locale di *ristorazione* e si vuol ordinare dell'acqua per bere, quale aggettivo o espressione si deve usare per indicare che si vorrebbe l'acqua a temperatura ambiente?"

Potreste spiegarmi quali sono le differenze di uso tra "ristoro" e "ristorazione"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Ristoro* nel suo significato più lato (e anche più alto) significa benessere o conforto.

L'espressione *locale di ristoro* non mi suona familiare, mentre invece sento spesso *luogo/posto di ristoro*, che probabilmente è la scelta più idiomatica. Anche se *locale di ristoro* è perfettamente comprensibile personalmente userei *locale di ristorazione* o *luogo di ristoro*.

Aggiungo che la parola *ristorazione* si riferisce a un settore commerciale ed è piuttosto fredda. *Luogo di ristoro* è un'espressione più calda che evoca immagini positive.